# external style sheet not loading in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load my external style sheet . It is loading but the style is being overrided by some other file.
How can i load my styles using ec

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>


    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` attribute to css rule you are trying to implement. It will force your rules to the matched set of element or classes!